# How do you authenticate long term tokens API Tokens?

Tags: rest, authorization, token, .net-core, api-design

So I have created an API that uses Token Authentication.
The API is currently being used mainly from the FE application so the token is created upon Login, stored in the FE user session and send over to API through the header on every request.

Now I want to start making my API public using the access token that is generated for every User upon Registration.

At first I thought I will generate a JWT token with long expiration date (20 years) but then I realized that the token is too long and from my experience Access Tokens are short.

So whats the available approaches for this situation?